# Apache2 is not starting after upgrading version 22:04

Tags: apache2, 22.04

After upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, then to 20.04 and finally to version 22.04, I got this error:

How can I fix it ?

```
root@vmi155065:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# sudo service apache2 status
× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-05-01 17:27:12 CEST; 1 day 20h ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 621 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 31ms

May 01 17:27:12 vmi155065.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 01 17:27:12 vmi155065.contaboserver.net apachectl[636]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load: Cannot >
May 01 17:27:12 vmi155065.contaboserver.net apachectl[621]: Action 'start' failed.
May 01 17:27:12 vmi155065.contaboserver.net apachectl[621]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 01 17:27:12 vmi155065.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 17:27:12 vmi155065.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 01 17:27:12 vmi155065.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: I think problem is fixed by changing - LoadModule php7_module "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so" to 
+ LoadModule php_module "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so" thank you. hope it will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! Please post the details of your solution as an answer, not a comment. This will ensure that your contribution is most helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 18):

I faced exactly this same issue while I did upgrade from Ubuntu 20 to 22. I made the following changes in order to make it work.

- `sudo a2dismod php7.4` (This is php ver. you had previously before upgrade)
- `sudo a2enmod php8.1` (This is php ver. you have after upgrade. Please verify the exact version by looking into `/etc/apache2/mods-available` folder. In my case I could see the latest ver. of php8.1 so did accordingly mentioned in this command)
- `systemctl restart apache2`
- `sudo apachectl configtest`

You might would like to know more about `a2dismod` and `a2enmode` commands? Here's the link which can answer it in detail [a2dismod, a2enmode](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/a2enmod.8.html).

Comment: Apache was able to start but Phpmyadmin does not work after these steps.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: worked, jammy 22.04

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and the steps shared in this thread helped resolve the problem.

[libphp module loading error](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2475324&page=5)

> To install PHP with success you have to install some dependencies
> first.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https
> ```
>
> This may be the difference between your troubles, and why mine works.
> This step is to import a PPA repository from **Ondřej Surý who is a
> renowned PHP and Debian developer and maintains its packages as well
> as Ubuntu’s packages.**
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
> ```
>
> run your update command only... Now see if this helps:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install php8.1 libapache2-mod-php8.1
> ```
>
> now reload:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl restart apache2
> ```
>
> check if it is working:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl status apache2
> ```
>
> ```
> systemctl status apache2
> \u25cf apache2.service - The Apache HTTP
> Server
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor prese>
>      Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-06-02 13:13:11 EDT; 8s ago
>        Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
>     Process: 14432 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/S>    Main PID: 14436 (apache2)
>       Tasks: 6 (limit: 4622)
>      Memory: 9.9M
>         CPU: 52ms
>      CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
>              \u251c\u250014436 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>              \u251c\u250014437 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>              \u251c\u250014438 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>              \u251c\u250014439 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>              \u251c\u250014440 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>              \u2514\u250014441 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just ensuring the php8.1 mod was installed worked for me.

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1
```

Comment: This is already in the question. Nothing new here.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt install -y libapache2-mod-php7.4

I have installed the libapache2-mod-php of the desired PHP version and it is working fine